# How can I get value from GroupedObservable?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I used groupBy iterator and got GroupedObservable object. Now I want to reduce that group to one T object. How can I get V from GroupedObservable? I can only see getKey() operator and autocomplete doesn't help me.

```
o.groupBy(player.getName())
 .flatMap(namePlayers -> {
       // How can I extract Observable<Player> from namePlayers

       // I want to write sth like this:
       .collect(Result::new, (result, player) -> result.mergeInfoFrom(player))
       .flatMapCompletable(result -> writeResultSomeWhere())
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this about rx-java or rx-java2? The answers given are for rx-java, not rx-java2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `GroupedObservable` is an `Observable` so you have the usual `map`, `filter`, `flatMap`, `collect`, etc. operators available.

```
Observable.range(1, 20)
.groupBy(v -> v % 2 == 0)
.flatMapMaybe(group -> {
    return group.reduce((a, b) -> a + b)
           .map(v -> "Group " + group.getKey() + " sum is " + v);
})
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getObservable()
    .flatMap(Observable::from)
    .groupBy(player-> player.getName())
    .flatMap(player-> player.count()
    .map(player -> player)
    .subscribe(//** your logic for subscription **//);
```

A simple example of using GroupedObservable.